# How to get link from a website

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I would like to know how to obtain the link "Add to cart / Purchase" from several sellers [here](https://www.g2a.com/bioshock-infinite-global.html).
When I inspect the code it says:

```
<td class="td-buy"><button class="mp-new--offers-buynow"><span class="icon-cart jq-ofert-buy"></span></button></td>
<button class="mp-new--offers-buynow"><span class="icon-cart jq-ofert-buy"></span></button>
<span class="icon-cart jq-ofert-buy"></span>
<<pseudo:before>></<pseudo:before>>
<span class="icon-cart jq-ofert-buy"></span>
<button class="mp-new--offers-buynow"><span class="icon-cart jq-ofert-buy"></span></button>
<td class="td-buy"><button class="mp-new--offers-buynow"><span class="icon-cart jq-ofert-buy"></span></button></td>
```

And if I click it doesn't show anywhere (that I know of), but once I clicked it, if I try to remove it from the basket it shows another link (it's not the same but it could help):
https://www.g2a.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/58009724/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZzJhLmNvbS9jaGVja291dC9jYXJ0Lw,,/
Thank you.

Comment: The click event for that element is probably a event handler in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a JavaScript or back-end event handler once user click on link "Add to cart / Purchase", mate :)